Internet satellite constellation at 5,000km
Imm really disturbed by the large number of Starlink satellites. I know that they have to be like this to reduce latency. But perhaps a moderate increase in latency is tolerable if it leads to a drastic reduction in satellites? So I thought: why not place a few dozen large satellites at around 5,000km?
The biggest issue I can think of is the radiation belt. Is there any way to protect the satellite from it?

Likely their engineering analysis considered various options and landed on the one they are implementing for reasons of cost, schedule, and/or performance. If launching is cheap (through SpaceX), why is the number of satellites (and the redundancy that comes with that) an issue?

@JonCuster There are a lot of reasons to be concerned about proliferation of satellites, from astronomical interference to concerns about collisions and debris. In LEO, a kessler cascade is less of an issue, in that the pieces from a collision or collision sequence would probably deorbit on a timescale of months or years rather than decades, but the potential to cause massive damage to LEO space infrastructure is not a small thing.

@JonCuster  From Astrophysical Journal Letters - Impact of the SpaceX Starlink Satellites on the Zwicky Transient Facility Survey Observations https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/ac470a

There are several major disadvantages to a MEO constellation compared to a LEO one.
Because of the inverse-square law, the fact that the satellites are about ten times further away means that either you need 100 times more power both in the satellite and in the mobile terminal, or the bandwidth is 100 times lower, or you need a much larger antenna, or any combination of the above.
As a result of the much higher power, bandwidth, and antenna requirements, the satellites are much more expensive. They also have to be much bigger. And that means makes them even more expensive, and also more expensive to launch. Because they are much more expensive, they need to have a much longer lifetime in order to amortize their cost. This, in turn, means that, on average, the satellites are built with much older technology. Compare that to Starlink, where the lifetime of the satellites is only 5 years and the first v1.0 ones are already being replaced with the latest and greatest v2 generation.
Also, the more satellites you build, the more you can benefit from economies of scale.
If you have fewer satellites, then obviously, each satellite must support more users. For example, the O3b and O3b mPOWER constellations are roughly in the orbit you propose (they are both around 8000 km), with a total of 31 satellites. That means that each satellite has to support almost 200 times as many users as a Starlink satellite today, or over 1300 times as many users compared to the full 42000 satellite Starlink constellation SpaceX has filed for permits for.
Since it is unlikely that each satellite will have 200–1300 times more bandwidth than a Starlink satellite, this means the bandwidth per user must be lower.
There's an easy fix for this, though: you can drastically increase the number of satellites … oh, wait.
All of this means that the cost will be much higher and the bandwidth will be much lower while the latency will also significantly increase. If you look at constellation which actually do this right now, you will notice that, unlike Starlink, they don't sell services to individual customers because that would be too expensive. Instead, e.g. O3b mPOWER is sold to telecommunication providers who use large ground stations to feed entire regions, or to airlines and cruise ship companies.
And if you look at the latest and greatest service which is offered, this service is called SES Cruise mPOWERED + Starlink, which, guess what, combines the O3b mPOWER constellation with Starlink.
As far as I can tell, a MEO constellation with a couple of dozen satellites does not have any real benefits over a LEO constellation with a couple of dozen satellites. It basically combines all the disadvantages of having fewer satellites with all the disadvantages of having them further away.

"As far as I can tell, a MEO constellation with a couple of dozen satellites does not have any real benefits over a LEO constellation with a couple of dozen satellites" presumably it'd have a much larger service area on the ground. Dozens of LEO satellites isn't what anyone is proposing, right?

The OP's concern is to reduce the number of satellites. They then jump to the conclusion that the way to reduce the number of satellites is to go to a 10x higher orbit. But you don't reduce the number of satellites by going to a higher orbit, you reduce the number of satellites by … reducing the number of satellites. There are satellite internet constellation in roughly comparable orbits to Starlink with far fewer satellites: Kuiper (~3000), OneWeb (648), Orbcomm (29). Starlink itself became operational before it had thousands of satellites.

Latency is a factor but it's a small one. When a satellite is closer to its customers, it can maintain more parallel links between itself and customers on the ground. This occurs because the individual beams need a certain amount of mutual angular separation lest they interfere with each other. If you move the satellites further away, angular separation will go down and signal-to-noise for each link will worsen. Distance is a factor but I think it is the ratio between: a) The strength of the signal you want, and b) The strength of the parallel signals off to the sides that you don't want, that has the strongest impact on signal-to-noise in the link budget.
Another factor is that when a satellite is further away it will be in the Earth's shadow longer. This increases the mass of the batteries that it needs to make it through its "night".
The last factor is that higher orbits require more delta-v, so fewer satellites can be deployed per launch. This is probably not a major concern if you happen to also be a launch company that routinely reuses 90% of the rocket hardware and 100% of the supporting infrastructure.
If you're worried about space collisions, I think it would be more cost-effective to invest in improving space traffic control than to re-architect the constellations to have higher orbits.
